# Merge multiple measurements into a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have some measurements organized in **.csv* files as follows:

```
m_number,value
0,0.154
1,0.785
…
55,0.578
NaN,NaN
0,1.214
1,0.742
…
```

So there is always a set of *x* measurements (*x* should be constant inside a single file but it's not guaranteed and I have to check this number) separated by a *NaN* line.

After reading the data into a dataframe, I want to reorganize it for later usage:

```
  m_number    value 1      value 2      value 3      value 4  
0        0      0.154        0.214        0.229        0.234       
1        1      0.785        0.742        0.714        0.771
...
55      55      0.578        0.647        0.597        0.623
```

Each set of measurements should be one column.

Here's a snippet of the code:

```py
split_index = df.index[df_benchmark['id'].isnull()]
df_sliced = pd.DataFrame()
for i, index in enumerate(split_index):
    if i == 0:
        df_sliced = df.loc[0:index - 1].copy()
    else:
        #ToDo: Rename first column to 'value 1' if more than 1 measurement
        temp = df['value'].loc[0:index - 1].copy()
        temp.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
        df_sliced['value '+str(i)] = temp
    df.drop(df.index[0:index - split_index[i - 1]], inplace=True)
```

The code works, but I do not like my current approach. So I'm asking if there's a better and more elegant solution for this problem.

Best,
Julz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `cumsum`, `set_index`, and `unstack` to do this is three lines of code:

```
#Create dummy data with 4 runs of 10 measures
df = pd.DataFrame({'m_number':np.tile(np.arange(10),4), 'value':np.random.random(40)})
```

<strike>#Use condition to find first run and increment using cumsum and unstack to create

MultiIndex column headers

df_u = df.set_index([df['m_number'].eq(0).cumsum(), df['m_number']])[['value']].unstack()</strike>

```
#Use condition to find first run and increment using cumsum and unstack to create  
#MultiIndex column headers (Corrected per comments below)
df_u = df.set_index([df['m_number'], df['m_number'].eq(0).cumsum()])[['value']].unstack()

#Flatten MultiIndex column headers 
df_u.columns = [f'{i}_{j}' for i, j in df_u.columns]

#Display results
df_u
```

Output:

```
           value_1   value_2   value_3   value_4
m_number                                        
0         0.919057  0.064409  0.288592  0.742759
1         0.449587  0.867031  0.193493  0.853700
2         0.551929  0.925111  0.895273  0.117306
3         0.487501  0.893696  0.696540  0.381469
4         0.389431  0.818801  0.771516  0.489404
5         0.790619  0.478995  0.023236  0.344112
6         0.015389  0.815073  0.195856  0.628263
7         0.068860  0.483731  0.752803  0.581106
8         0.109404  0.281335  0.330910  0.909965
9         0.695120  0.538676  0.766864  0.247283
```

Comment: Thank you. This looks much cleaner. However, the output is not exactly what I need. Using your dummy data the output should have only 4 columns (one for each set of measurements) and 10 rows. So m_number should range from 0 to 9 and value from 1 to 4.

Comment: @julz okay... I'll have a look and see what I can modify to get desired output.   Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: @Julz... okay, I think I corrected the expected output.  Changing the order of the `set_index` and unstacking the inner most level transpose the number as you have descripted here.  If I understand you correctly.

Comment: Yes, thank you. Now it does exactly what I need. One comment: I just played a bit around with your code to understand what's happening. I noticed that it would have been enough to use unstack(level=0) on your first solution to achieve the same result.

Comment: @Julz... yes you are absolutely correct.  That would have been the most efficient way to change the code.  Thank you for that oberservation.  Happy coding!